# How make PostgreSQL consider all java.sql.Timestamp as being in the UTC "zone"?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I want PostgreSQL to assume UTC always. This works fine: I insert a `java.sql.Timestamp` into PostgreSQL like so:

```
insert into posts(created_at, ...) values (? at time zone 'UTC', ...)
```

But if I remove *"at time zone 'UTC'"*, PostgreSQL somehow converts the timestamp to my local time zone. I'm afraid that sometimes I'll forget to append *"at time zone 'UTC'"* when I'm inserting or updating timestamps. Is there no way to have PostgreSQL automatically handle all timestamps as UTC times? So I can remove *"at time zone 'UTC'"* everywhere.

`created_at` is a `timestamp without time zone`. Not sure if this setting matters: (it's UTC already, at least when I test via `psql`)

```
SELECT  current_setting('TIMEZONE');
current_setting 
-----------------
UTC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work: Specifying a UTC calendar when saving the `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
thePreparedStatement.setTimestamp(bindPosition, timestamp, calendarUtcTimeZone)
```

Where `calendarUtcTimeZone` is:

```
def calendarUtcTimeZone = ju.Calendar.getInstance(UtcTimeZone, DefaultLocale)
private val UtcTimeZone = ju.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
private val DefaultLocale = ju.Locale.getDefault(ju.Locale.Category.FORMAT)
```

And the calendar is needed when loading the timestamp and converting it to a `java.util.Date` too:

```
  def getDate(rs: js.ResultSet, column: String): ju.Date = {
    val timestamp = rs.getTimestamp(column, calendarUtcTimeZone)
    if (timestamp eq null) null: ju.Date
    else new ju.Date(timestamp.getTime)
  }
```

Now I can remove all `at timestamp 'UTC'` — at least I think so right now.

Here's the Javadoc about `setTimestamp`:

```
 * With a
 *  <code>Calendar</code> object, the driver can calculate the timestamp
 * taking into account a custom timezone.  If no
 * <code>Calendar</code> object is specified, the driver uses the default
 * timezone, which is that of the virtual machine running the application.
```